# IE returns same last radio button value using class jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, internet-explorer

I'm facing some strange issue in IE.

HTML Code:

```
  <input type="radio" name="radio" value="10" class="sample" />
   <input type="radio" name="radio" value="20" class="sample" />
  <input type="checkbox" name="radio" value="30" class="sample" />
  <input type="checkbox" name="radio" value="40" class="sample" />
```

jQuery code:

```
 $(".sample").each(function(){          
        console.log($(this).val());     
         
     })
```

jQuery version: 1.7.1

In IE9 the console log returns `40,40,40,40` in the each loop, but same working fine in all other browser, returning `10,20,30,40`.

Any solution other than changing the jQuery version.

Comment: Will replacing `$(this).val()` with `this.value` change anything?

Comment: Could the reason be that they all share the same `name attribute` value?

Comment: I'm unable to reproduce your issue

Comment: I took your @Ani's answer and ported in 1.7.1 off of cdnjs.com, worked fine on IE10 in IE9 mode. Perhaps only "true" IE9 has this issue? I've run into that before where IE8 mode is different than "true" IE8. Can you please tell us whether you are actually using IE9, or just IE10 in compat mode?

Answer (score 0):

Works fine on IE9 for me. Link: http://jsfiddle.net/qtfnN/2/

Using jQuery version: 1.7.1

Try closing the js function properly:

```
$(".sample").each(function(){          
    console.log($(this).val());     

 });
```

Comment: OP specified jQuery 1.7.1